# Redirecting from preview url to post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I have foolishly sent out an email with a link to the preview of a post I made. The url was:

.../videos/?preview_id=14285&preview_nonce=d402403197&preview=true

When someone tries to visit the draft/preview URL, they are not able to access the post, even after it has been published and made public.

I have tried redirects without success. I still get the message:
Sorry, you are not allowed to preview drafts.

Answer (score 0):

The use of [`is_preview()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_preview/) and [`template_redirect` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) should work (untested):

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {
    if ( ! is_preview() ) {
        return;
    }

    $permalink = get_permalink( $_GET['preview_id'] );

    nocache_headers();
    wp_redirect( $permalink );

    exit;
} );
```